# nmake: command not found when building OpenSSL

Tags: windows, openssl, nmake

I'm trying to follow the installation instruction for OpenSSL on Windows using this instruction on git bash.

On Windows (only pick one of the targets for configuration):

```
$ perl Configure { VC-WIN32 | VC-WIN64A | VC-WIN64I | VC-CE }
$ nmake
$ nmake test
$ nmake install
```

but it failed to recognized nmake. The command resulted in ***`nmake: command not found`***.

Has someone know about nmake? Or am I doing it wrong?

Comment: [Announcing Visual C++ Build Tools 2015 – standalone C++ tools for build environments](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2015/11/02/announcing-visual-c-build-tools-2015-standalone-c-tools-for-build-environments/). You don't have to download Visual Studio, or subject yourself to the [gimmicks and expiring trials](http://www.google.com/search?q=visual+studio+expiring+trial).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> $ perl Configure { VC-WIN32 | VC-WIN64A | VC-WIN64I | VC-CE }
> $ nmake
> ```
>
> but it failed to recognized nmake.

Download and install the [Visual C++ build tools](https://aka.ms/buildtools). You don't have to download Visual Studio, or subject yourself to the [gimmicks and expiring trials](http://www.google.com/search?q=visual+studio+expiring+trial). The Visual C++ build tools provide everything you need to work from the command line.

Then, open a developer prompt, `cd` into the OpenSSL directory and perform the procedure. To open a developer prompt: Start → All Programs → Microsoft Visual Studio → Visual Studio Tools → Visual Studio Command Prompt. Also see [Developer Command Prompt for Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229859(v=vs.110).aspx) on MSDN.

Answer (score 1):

nmake is a Microsoft build tool for C++. Download [Visual C++ Express](https://www.visualstudio.com/de-de/products/visual-studio-express-vs) to get it. Unfortunately you can't get just nmake on its own, you have to download the entire toolchain.